# CustomControl, xml attributes not working with data binding

Tags: java, android, attributes, custom-controls, android-databinding

I have set custom attrs in my custom control, like this:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyControl" tools:ignore="ResourceName">
    <attr name="ms_hide_arrow" format="boolean"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Then, my control is used in my application xml layout, this works:

```
 <MyControl
  .................
  app:ms_hide_arrow="false"
/>
```

But if I try to use data binding to provide value, like this:

```
 <MyControl
  .................
  app:ms_hide_arrow="@{user.hideArrow}"
/>
```

I'm getting error message:

> Error:(183, 34) Cannot find the setter for attribute
>   'app:ms_hide_arrow' with parameter type boolean on...

What am I missing? If I use standard Android control, for example standard spinner, I can set its attributes with data binding without any problem.

Should I do anything specific to get my custom control able to be used with data binding?

[added]
Problem solved by adding setter like this:

```
public void setMs_hide_arrow(boolean v)
{
  hideArrow = v;
}
```

However, there is still problem when I try to use 2-way binding, so in xml I set:

`app:ms_hide_arrow="@={user.hideArrow}`"

End getter:

```
public boolean getMs_hide_arrow()
{
   return hideArrow ;
}
```

I am getting error message about missing getter:

> Error:(171, 9) Cannot find the getter for attribute
>   'app:ms_hide_arrow' with value type boolean on ...

Getter is there, what's wrong?

Comment: `setMsHideArrow(boolean)` method in `MyControl`?

Comment: Well, it works, am I dumb? Standard controls don't expose any setters, but they still working. For example, I can user `android:entries` for Spinner. Spinner does not expose any `setEntries` method though

Comment: see `AbsSpinnerBindingAdapter.java` in `android.databinding.adapter` package, if you dont have sources see: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/android-6.0.0_r7/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters/AbsSpinnerBindingAdapter.java

Comment: There is still something wrong. I tried 2-way binding and it complains for missing getter, even if getter is there. Any ideas?

Comment: so whats the error you are getting?

Comment: The sam as previously, Cannot find getter. But getter is there

Comment: Question updated. Anybody? Why getter is ignored?

Comment: Yes. But camel case needs to be there, the same syntax as setter, correspnding to attribute name. I have also tested with other attributes, without any camel ases in names (to be sure) always getter ignored for 2-way binding. I'm confused. 1-way binding with setter only, works fine

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/InverseBindingAdapter.html

Comment: You don't undestand. 2-way binding works with standard controls, I have getter and setter configured in my model. There must be something missing in my custom control. Or please be more specific, I don't understand what do you mean exactly. Should I use InverseBindingAdapter inside my control?

Comment: see TimePickerBindingAdapter.java, TextViewBindingAdapter.java and TabHostBindingAdapter.java

Comment: I can't see how is it related to my problem, sorry

Comment: open `TextViewBindingAdapter.java ` and see how `android:text` two-way databinding for `EditText` is implemented

Comment: Do you mean this? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/android-6.0.0_r7/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters/TextViewBindingAdapter.java I can't see it there

Comment: here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/master/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters/TextViewBindingAdapter.java#78

Answer (score 1):

create bindingAdapter like this for example in your view model(you can create a class for all binderAdapters):

```
@BindingAdapter("msHideArrow")
public static void hideArrow(View View, boolean isVisible) {
    if (isVisible) {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

and in your Xml file:

```
 <MyControl
  .................
  app:msHideArrow="@{user.hideArrow}"
/>
```